# How to Log In to Website using WebRequest

Tags: html, f#, webrequest

I am trying to make a program log into a website using WebRequest and then copy the html page that comes after login into a string.

```
   let returnHTML (url : string) =
    let request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(System.Uri(url))
    let response = request.GetResponse()
    let stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    let reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream)
    let webstring = reader.ReadToEnd ()
    webstring

   printfn "%A" (returnHTML "myURL")
```

The above code copies the login page into a string because i have not implemented some sort of login session yet. This is where i hope some of you can break it down for dummies.

The form that needs login into looks like this :

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="https://aamanasdasdad" method="post">
    <p>
            <label for="user_login">Brugernavn eller e-mailadresse<br />
            <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" /></label>
    </p>
    <p>
            <label for="user_pass">Password<br />
            <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" /></label>
    </p>
            <p class="forgetmenot"><label for="rememberme"><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever"  /> Husk mig</label></p>
    <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Log ind" />
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="https://aamansasns.asdasddk/wp-admin/admiadasdad" />
            <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
    </p>
```

Can someone please guide me on how to reach the last step?